# Inconsistency in receiving push notification

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I found some weird behavior in push notification. My iPod app receives push notifications till last week with no issues. Then I found that my app is not receiving push notifications, and I changed the certificates and it worked fine, and after 2 days its not working. And I repeated the same process and same kinda problem. I was wondering why this happens?

**NOTE** I am using my own java based server to send push notification. I am sure that my certification are not expired. At the time of this problem the badge id is also not visible with my application icon.??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: last week, I also faced same problem. most of the time push alert working fine with latest OS 4.3 rather than older OS devices. waiting for answer on your question!

Comment: @KingOfBliss Can you provide some code for us to look at?

Comment: @Fulvio Whats there with code?\

Comment: Which format are you using for the sending, normal or enhanced?

Comment: @nduplesis whts d diff btwn normal and enhanced?

Comment: Are you getting any kind of error messages from your server?  In other words, are you able to send the notification but then it just disappears or are you unable to even connect to APNS to send the notification?

Comment: @Dan: Im not even geeting any error message from server. Thats y i coudlnt track this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure a few things

1. You are using the correct combination of production or dev pem and the APNS or sandbox server URL
2. Check the Feedback services to ensure whether you are getting any errors

I faced similar issues with my 3GS running OS 4.1 last week. It started working after I restarted my device. Try doing that and see if it works.

Comment: @IostlnTransit I have done everything u said. No use. Thanks for ur help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to update the device token in the database of you provider. I guess some updates in your iOS/certificates may changed your device token. Just make a test around that.

Comment: Its coded such that the device token in db is always updating. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try lostInTransit's solution and also check for your internet connectivity. I also faced this issue with my iPod sometimes the push notifications not come in my iPod. Try this -

Install facebook iPhone app on your device.
Send a test push notification from your server.
If the notification does not come then do something with facebook which should generate the notification. 
If the notification from facebook does not come it means its related to your net connectivity.And your code is perfect.

Sometimes I see that when my iPod is on DHCP it does not receive the notification but when I assign it a static network (dedicated IP) it works fine.