# Parse Push Notifications come through inconsistently

Tags: ios, ipad, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

*(Note that this question is different from most Parse Push Notification questions because pushes **are** working, just inconsistently within the same hour. So this is not a duplicate of similar questions like [Inconsistency in receiving push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026690/inconsistency-in-receiving-push-notification) .)*

I've been using Parse for several projects for about a year now, and this whole time, I've observed that push notifications go through inconsistently for ios.

My questions are,

1. **What's going on?**
2. **Is there anything I can do about it?**
3. **Is this an issue with Parse, or would I encounter the same issues using any method of sending push notification requests to Apple?**

Eg, this morning I noticed that a daily push notification that was supposed to come in yesterday never did. To investigate the problem, I attempted to generate a push notification by using a button in my app which calls a Parse cloud code function that triggers a push notification to be sent.

I did this a few times over a few minutes, and **confirmed using the Parse site that my Parse app sent the push notification and that Parse considers it to have been successful.**

But **no push came through to my iPad.** This has happened before in the same way many times -- it's like there are periods of time when pushes just never go through; sometimes they do come through 15 minutes later, though that didn't happen this morning -- they were just gone and never delivered.

I tried **using the Parse site to manually send a push to the same exact user installation, and that worked fine;** then i took the "where" and "data" json sections from the previously sent (but never received) pushes, and **pasted them into a curl commandline push command, with the proper application and rest api ids. That worked perfectly and instantly**, and showed up instantly and properly on the ipad.

**After that, the push request from within the app seemed to work fine!**

So there doesn't appear to be any issue with the app itself -- both the successful and unsuccessful push attempts looked the same to the Parse servers, at least according to the push notifications web GUI...

It's as if there is inconsistent behavior **after** the push request is initiated by Parse and sent to Apple. That could be on Parse's end or on Apple's end.

What's strange is that it seems as though I was able to temporarily fix the problem by using other methods to get Parse to send push notifications to that device. It's almost as if on Parse or Apple's end, there was a setting or cache that was blocking the device from receiving pushes following some pattern, and by breaking that pattern and getting a different push to go through, pushes following the pattern of the original pushes could now go through fine.

Screenshot from my Parse app page. Pushes that never arrived on device are at 10:06 and 10:09. Pushes at 10:14 and later all came through fine:
[image: Pushes that never arrived on device are at 10:06 and 10:09. Pushes at 10:14 and later all came through fine.]

Detail of the 10:09 push, initiated via my app, which **failed to arrive on phone:**
[image: Detail of the 10:09 push, which failed to arrive on phone]

Detail of the 10:21 push, initiated via curl from commandline, which **appeared on the phone fine.** Note inclusion of deviceType:
[image: Detail of the 10:21 push, which appeared on the phone fine]

Detail of the 10:22 push, initiated via my app, which **appeared on the phone fine:**
[image: Detail of the 10:22 push, initiated via my app, which appeared on the phone fine]

From my description, you might wonder if the push merely came through so fast that I didn't have a chance to see it before leaving the app; or perhaps it might have arrived in the app during the last split second of its being in the foreground on the ipad. But I specifically coded the push request in the app so that it does not submit the request until you leave the app by using the home button or the device power button. I have confirmed multiple times that this functionality works -- the push is not arriving while the app is in the foreground, so it should always appear on the lockscreen or as a banner at the top of the screen and in the Notifications drawer.

My list of possible explanations:

1. Requests are formatted differently: no, examine the successful and unsuccessful push where and data sections; Parse has clearly processed these requests the same way, so there seems to be no difference in the formatting
2. Requests are different packet/payload sizes, and larger size is being rejected by Apple: look at requests according to Parse above; content is identical. (I have of course seen much larger data payload pushes be rejected.)
3. Connectivity on the client side was not consistent: always possible, but very unlikely here. This ipad has no cellular data, only wifi, the signal is strong and consistent, and other internet functions worked within the same minute as each of these requests.
4. Parse is behaving inconsistently during different times, completely outside my control, and showing no signs of this in app web GUI: seems possible. But why, then, does it seem as though I have the power to fix the functionality by getting differently formed pushes to go through?
5. Parse is behaving inconsistently and I do have some control, though this is undocumented and due to software and/or architecture bugs: this is a decent guess.
6. Apple is behaving inconsistently during different times, completely outside my control, and showing no signs of this in app web GUI: seems possible. But why, then, does it seem as though I have the power to fix the functionality by getting differently formed pushes to go through?
7. Apple is behaving inconsistently and I do have some control, though this is undocumented and due to software and/or architecture bugs: this is a decent guess.

Any other ideas of possible explanations are very welcome!

I'd also love to know if others have observed this sort of behavior.

**Edit 2015-06-23:**

To clarify, these are all silent push notifications.

Pushes deliver successfully 100% of the time the device is unplugged, IF they have already been working in the last hour or so. And we have witnessed them not coming through when the device IS plugged in many, many times. This behavior seems to have been essentially the same before ios 8 and in the present day, with ios 8.3.

This has been observed on multiple devices, both ipads and iphones.

**Edit 2015-06-30:**

Parse's developer support MVP, Hector Ramos, responded to my post of this same question on the Facebook bug submission site. He says it sounds to him like behavior they have seen in the past on Apple's part. There are still aspects of this that are confusing, like whether or not there's anything we can do about it or Parse can do about it...

Comment: as for 2: Apple Push payloads are limited to 255 bytes

Comment: What type of push does this result in being sent - a foreground or silent push? Silent pushes are unpredictable (will arrive immediately if device is charging, otherwise could be anytime). Also are you testing on the dev or prod environments, they behave differently from each other.

Comment: @Shai: yes, but the size isn't varying here.

Comment: @Gruntcakes: INTERESTING! Do you have a source for that? I'm testing in production, like a boss :)

Comment: By lots and lots of observations and testing - the two environments don't behave the same so you should always use production to see how it will behave once release. The charging thing is a known change that Apple applied in iOS 8.1 but is undocumented -  I know as an Apple engineer replied to a discussion on the Apple dev forum. Its something which can easily be verified just by plugging/unplugging the device and sending pushes and see what happens. When charging 99% of the time they will appear in seconds, when not charging its only about 10% of the time (for silent pushes)

Comment: Hm, that actually doesn't sound like the behavior we have been observing. Pushes deliver successfully 100% of the time the device is unplugged, IF they have already been working in the last hour or so. And we have witnessed them not coming through when the device IS plugged in many, many times. This behavior seems to have been essentially the same before ios 8 and in the present day, with ios 8.3. So maybe that's not what's going on.